# Is there a way to create a template literal that uses a for loop value in the name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to avoid repitition with my code and make it a reusable as I can for the future. 
What I'd like to do, ideally, is use a for loop to both iterate through an array of elements and then also use the value of 'i' to change the href attribute on the elements.
(I don't know if I explained myself very well there. Words are hard)
This is what I've got at the moment which does create a string with the right value but I want it not to be a string. 
For the example - option.data.pod1URL = https://www.blah.com
I need it to have the actual URL attached to that variable. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way?

```
for(let i = 0; i <= popItems.length; i++){
    $(popItems[i]).find('a').attr('href', `${('options.data.pod'+(i+1)+'URL')}`);
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `attr('href', options.data[\`pod${i+1}URL\`])` (or something close to that). Currently creating a string, so that's what you get--you want to access `option.data` with a dynamic key. I think.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that now. This has been bugging me for a good 30 minutes

Comment: Genius! Thank you. You've saved me an afternoon of stress